# selectedindexchanged event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i have three `dropdownlists` with `autopostaback=true`,but the problem is that for second `dropdownlist` only `pageload` is called but it's `selectedindexchanged` is not firing! what can i do?(`dropdownlists` are in `updatepanel` )

```
EDIT:
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DDL_d1.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = null;
            DbAccessor db = new DbAccessor();
            dr = db.SqlSelectS("true", "SELECT Fname FROM [Tbl_Amoozesh]");
            DDL_d1.Items.Clear();
            while (dr.Read())
                DDL_d1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
    protected void d1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DDL_d1.AutoPostBack = false;
        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        DbAccessor db = new DbAccessor();
        dr = db.SqlSelectS(DDL_d1.SelectedValue,"SELECT Fname FROM [Tbl_Amoozesh] where Fname = @a");
        DDL_d2.Items.Clear();
        DDL_d2.Items.Add(new ListItem("hi"));
        while (dr.Read())
            DDL_d2.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
        db.Dispose();




    }
    protected void d2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        DbAccessor db = new DbAccessor();
        dr = db.SqlSelectS(DDL_d2.SelectedValue, "SELECT Lname FROM [Tbl_Amoozesh] where Fname = @a");
        DDL_d3.Items.Clear();
        while (dr.Read())
            DDL_d3.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
        db.Dispose();

    }
```

Comment: Do you have any `DataBind` calls on Load? remove those. DataBinds should happen only on the first request when `IsPostBack` is false.

Comment: Post your code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put an asynchronous trigger in your updatepanel. Try this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="up1" runat="server" updatemode="conditional">
   <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
   </Triggers>
   <ContentTemplate>
      <%-- your content here --%>
      <asp:DropdownList id="ddl" AutoPostback="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="handler" />
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: but there is a problem for last parameter SelectedIndexChanged not fired(only once is firing) for other elements is ok

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem. I was also populating my `dropdownlist` from a database table and I tried everything including setting `AutoPostBack = true` on the control. It turns out this is a known bug that you can resolve by making index 0 a dummy item like 'Select a person'. Check out the post here:

https://forums.asp.net/t/1275349.aspx?Dropdownlist+not+firing+SelectedIndexChanged+on+first+item+with+autopostback+true

This solved my problem.